# Append/concat text to pipe "select" result

Tags: powershell

When I execute the following powershell script,

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership someuser | select Name
```

it will return

```
Name
----
Domain Users
```

How can I return result appending "_1234", like:

```
Name
----
Domain Users_1234
```

Comment: are you wanting to FIND such a group name, CHANGE the found group name, or simply add the text to the displayed group name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a calculated property.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership someuser | Select-Object -property @{name='Name';e={"$($_.name)_1234"}}
```